# Clone from GitHub.com “Temporary failure in name resolution” error

Tags: git

I encountered problems downloading Xilinx from GitHub. I have googled and tried various methods to clone it. Below is the error:

```
mohsin@mohsin-VirtualBox:~$ git clone https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx.git
Cloning into 'linux-xlnx'...
fatal: unable to look up github.com (port 9418) (Temporary failure in name resolution)
```

I tried with:

```bsh
git config --global http.proxy
git config --global https.proxy
```

But I still have the same error.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 in a VirtualBox 6.1.

Comment: looks like dns issue. Please, post output of: ping -c 2 github.com

Comment: now i'm getting this error:ping: github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: i guess you dont have specified nameservers in your resolv.conf file. Try to execute this code in your command line: sudo echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf
It will add google public dns "8.8.8.8" to your nameservers list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I added that nameserver but unfortunately i still have the same error.any other idea?

Comment: if you need fast solution, you can just add record for github to your hosts file by executing this command: echo 140.82.114.4 github.com | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts    

   But this is not the best option. Please update your post by adding this code output: cat  /etc/resolv.conf && cat /etc/nsswitch.conf

Comment: echo 140.82.114.4 github.com | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts.This command resolved my problem thank you so much Metalic

Comment: i wouldn't hard-code github.com's host (what the /etc/hosts command does) because IPs can be subject to change, hence why we often refer to them with DNS.

Answer (score 2):

To check resolution on ubuntu, run:

```
$ sudo resolvectl query github.com
github.com: 140.82.114.3                       -- link: wlp2s0

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 1.3ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```

To update it (for example, to google's dns server), take the link name from the previous command (or check `ifconfig`) and then substitute it for mine, `wlp2s0`, in the following command:

```
$ sudo resolvectl dns wlp2s0 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: `sudo resolvectl query github.com` failed with error: `sd_bus_open_system: No such file or directory`